# How to print a string array which is part of a JSON consists of other attributes

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

in the client side, I have a json object which I receive from REST service somewhere. This object has more that one attribute, one of them is a String array. I want some assistance on how to print this array using angular JS code embedded within html. 
this is my JSON object:

```
[

    "title": "Developing a System for Information Management in Disaster Relief",
    "url": "http://scholar.google.com/scholar",
    "relatedTitles": 
    [
        "Distributed robotic sensor networks",
        "Improving information access for emergency",
        "Tangible and wearable user interfaces for",
        "Non-parametric inferenc",
        "Airborne near-real-time monitoring of assembly" 
    ]
]
```

and here is how the html ng-repeat looks like.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
        <td>{{publication.title}}</td>
        <td>{{publication.url}}</td>
        <td>{{publication.relatedTitles}} </tr>
```

Note:"publications" is the JSON object name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to print it. If you want it like and array, joined with commas for example use this html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
    <td>{{publication.title}}</td>
    <td>{{publication.url}}</td>
    <td>{{publication.relatedTitles.join(', ')}}
</tr>
```

Else, if you want with a `<span>` tag each for example, you can do another ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
    <td>{{publication.title}}</td>
    <td>{{publication.url}}</td>
    <td>
        <span ng-repeat="relatedTitle in publication.relatedTitles">
            {{publication.relatedTitles}} 
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `ng-repeat`'s

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
        <td>{{publication.title}}</td>
        <td>{{publication.url}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="title in publication.relatedTitles">
               <td>{{title}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
    <td>{{publication.title}}</td>
    <td>{{publication.url}}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="title in publication.relatedTitles">
      {{title}}<br>
      </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```